# Help me evaluate this casting

Tags: c++, opengl

I found this in the PowerVR mesh drawing code and I don't really know how to read it.

```
&((unsigned short*)0)[3 * mesh.sBoneBatches.pnBatchOffset[batchNum]]
```

What is going on here?  Is this a reference to void cast as an unsigned short pointer and then offset by (3*mesh(etc...) + batchNum)?  It's breaking my brain.

It's found in the context of a glDrawElements call:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, i32Tris * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 
               &((unsigned short*)0)[3 * mesh.sBoneBatches.pnBatchOffset[batchNum]]);
```

Comment: It's found in the context of a glDrawElements call:

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, i32Tris * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, &((unsigned short*)0)[3 * mesh.sBoneBatches.pnBatchOffset[batchNum]]);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's go from the inside out.

```
(unsigned short*)0
```

This is casting `0` to an unsigned short pointer. This will be used for computing a memory offset, computed in terms of the size of an unsigned short.

```
3 * mesh.sBoneBatches.pnBatchOffset[batchNum]
```

This is, presumably, the offset in memory of some batch of triangles. A triangle is composed of 3 shorts, so it looks like they are storing an offset in terms of numbers of triangles, and then multiplying by 3 to get the number of shorts.

```
((unsigned short*)0)[3 * mesh.sBoneBatches.pnBatchOffset[batchNum]]
```

This is now using that `0` pointer to find the memory location of the given offset. This would normally return the value of that memory location, but they want a pointer to pass into glDrawElements, so the use the `&` operator to get a pointer to that memory location:

```
&((unsigned short*)0)[3 * mesh.sBoneBatches.pnBatchOffset[batchNum]]
```

Comment: why isn't the applicaiton crashing at step 3 ? (attempt to get the value of a bad memory location)

Comment: Because of the & operator, the value is never accessed. Just the address of the value.

Comment: It didn't know about this particularity of the language. Doesn't seem "natural" to me. Thanks.

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you.  One more question, is a 0 pointer the same concept as a void pointer?

Comment: No, but C mandates that the NULL pointer converts to an integral 0 and vice versa, and C++ mandates that NULL is represented by 0.

Answer (score 2):

It's computing a byte offset -- 3 * mesh.sBoneBatches.pnBatchOffset[batchNum] is the index.  Using 0 as the pointer means that the address will be just the offset value, nothing else.

Comment: In essence, it's `3 * mesh.sBoneBatches.pnBatchOffset[batchNum] * sizeof(unsigned short)` (though with a different type), assuming that `unsigned short[]` arrays are aligned naturally with no padding.

Comment: I dont get it . Shouldn't "((unsigned short*)0)[...]" dereference a null pointer, thus leading in unexpected behavior ?

Comment: @TheSamFrom1984: No, because dereferencing is not needed to take the address.  This is a common trick in C, and is theoretically illegal in C++, but generally works anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Really, this kind of hack is due to OpenGL expressing offsets inside Buffer Objects through the pointer argument of glDrawElements.

```
glDrawElements(mode, count, type, void* indices)
```

`indices` represents either a client-side memory **pointer** or a server-side memory **offset** based on the binding of `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB`

It's interesting to dig a bit deeper... [From the VBO specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_buffer_object.txt):

> Is it legal C to use pointers as offsets?
>
> We haven't come to any definitive conclusion about this.  [...]
>
> Varying opinions have been expressed as to whether this is legal,
>   although no one could provide an example of a real system where
>   any problems would occur.

Answer (score 0):

Its an obfuscated way of computing

```
sizeof(unsigned short) * 3 * mesh.sBoneBatches.pnBatchOffset[batchNum]
```

but since it doesn't actually save any characters, its not a very good obfuscation

Comment: Only one caveat - it returns a pointer to address N, not N as a number.