# How do I use a pointer as an offset?

Tags: c, opengl

This issue originally came up in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645309/help-me-evaluate-this-casting) of mine where I was having trouble reading some bit of code.  The answer turned out to be that this line

```
&((GLushort *)0)[3 * mesh.sBoneBatches.pnBatchOffset[batchNum]]
```

evaluates to be a pointer.  And it's used in

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, i32Tris * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, &((unsigned short*)0)[3 * mesh.sBoneBatches.pnBatchOffset[batchNum]]);
```

where it is **interpreted as an offset** to draw a subset of vertex indices.

My code currently requires me to do by hand some of what openGL is doing in the glDrawElements, and I can't figure out how to use the pointer as an offset.  glDrawElements uses an array of indices (named vertexIndices in my code), so I tried something like this:

```
vertexIndices[&((GLushort *)0)[3 * mesh.sBoneBatches.pnBatchOffset[batchNum]]]
```

but that obviously failed.

***EDIT 1:***
   I just tried this and it compiles... still not sure if it's correct though. `vertexIndices + (uint) &((GLushort *)0)[3 * mesh.sBoneBatches.pnBatchOffset[batchNum]]`

Comment: I guess I'm not super comfortable with the whole idea of 'pointer as offset'. I suppose I could think of all pointers as offsets from 0, but that still doesn't help me with the syntax here :-p.

Comment: When I saw your original question, I thought the same thing I think now - how is glDrawElements not crashing when it tries to access the passed-in vertex array when your vertex array isn't a valid memory address (and just merely an offset)?

Comment: I apologize that this question is a little brief on the details, it's an extension of another question (which is linked in the post) which fully explores why glDrawElements does not crash when it is passed this invalid memory address.

Comment: The comments on my answer clarify things sufficiently :). I deleted the cranky comment.

Comment: Ahh, it's not crashing due to you setting up a GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sort of idiom is used occasionally in C.  It is good practice to encapsulate the calculation in a macro, but that is a side issue.

The trouble you are running into is this:  Yes, the type of the expression is a pointer type, but the interpretation of the expression (as you realize) is an offset.  Therefore, the expression value is only valid when cast to an int.

In the `glDrawElements()` call, the expression value is being coerced to int by C's parameter rules.

In the array index, there is no coercion rule which would automatically cast the expression to int.  You must supply the int cast:

`vertexIndices[(int)&((GLushort *)0)[3 * mesh.sBoneBatches.pnBatchOffset[batchNum]]]`

Better form would be:

```
#define OFFSET_OF_GLUSHORT_STUFF (m, N) \
    ((int)&((GLushort *)0)[3 * (m).sBoneBatches.pnBatchOffset[(N)]])
/*...*/ vertexIndices[OFFSET_OF_GLUSHORT_STUFF(mesh, batchNum)];
```

WHOA, you just changed your question to indicate that you  are trying to use this offset to calculate the pointer to an array element.  In that case, DO NOT use this offset-based approach, because if you are passing a compatible pointer type, the pointer math should work directly.  And if you are not passing a compatible pointer type, havoc will ensue.

You must get this to work using some direct pointer math, for your code's safety.

Answer (score 2):

What's being passed to `glDrawElements` is a pointer *to* an offset, not a pointer *as* an offset. Your mysterious line of code is equivalent to:

```
size_t offset = ((GLushort*)0)[3 * mesh.sBoneBatches.pnBatchOffset[batchNum]];
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, i32Tris * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, &offset);
```

In other words, `glDrawElements()` isn't using the fourth parameter as an offset directly, but a pointer to an offset value. This is clear from the [OpenGL documentation](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/man_pages/hardcopy/GL/html/gl/drawelements.html), which has the following signature for glDrawElements:

```
  void glDrawElements( GLenum mode,
               GLsizei count,
               GLenum type,
               const GLvoid *indices );
```

And the explanation:

> indices - Specifies a **pointer to the location** where the indices are stored.

(Emphasis mine.)

Aside: The offset calculation is a little weird, but valid for the reasons outlined in the answer to your other question. It's clearer and more stylistically normal to write that as:

```
size_t offset = sizeof(GLushort) * 3 * mesh.sBoneBatches.pnBatchOffset[batchNum];
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should mention that I was using Vertex Buffer Objects, and in that particular case (because it's a server side calculation) openGL uses pointers AS offsets, instead of using the actual pointer as it would in client side calculations (like glDrawArrays)

Comment: From opengl.org:

        RESOLVED: When the default buffer object (object zero) is
        bound, all pointers behave as real pointers.  When any other
        object is bound, all pointers are treated as offsets.
        Conceptually, one can imagine that buffer object zero is a buffer
        object sitting at base NULL and with an extent large enough that
        it covers all of the system's virtual address space.

        Note that this approach essentially requires that binding points
        be client (not server) state.

Answer (score 1):

Calculations based on an offset of zero *can* work in some compilers, but are not *guaranteed* to do so. ANSI C offers you [the `offsetof` operator](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/stddef.h.html) in `stddef.h` to allow you to calculate offsets of members of a struct.